# Upsert in YugabyteDB YCQL with 1 statement

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am trying to do an insert (if a record does not exist) or a conditional update (if it does).
Is there a way to do this with just one statement (insert or update) without doing a separate select?
If not, then just for an update, is there a way to perform a conditional update (on a timestamp column)?

Here's an example DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE test.mytable (
    h1 text,
    h2 text,
    name text,
    event_ts timestamp,
    event_id text,
    ev_type text,
    payload text,
    payload_full text,
    created_ts timestamp,
    modified_ts timestamp,
    update_ts timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((h1, h2), name, event_ts, event_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name ASC, event_ts DESC, event_id ASC)
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND transactions = {'enabled': 'true'};
CREATE INDEX consumer_event_idx ON test.mytable ((h1, h2), event_ts, event_id, name) INCLUDE (ev_type, payload, created_ts, modified_ts)
    WITH transactions = {'enabled': 'true'};
```

Here's my update statement and the corresponding error message - what am I doing wrong?

```
ycqlsh:cdp> UPDATE test.mytable set payload = 'payload_updated'
       ... WHERE h1 = '1' and h2 = 'return' and name = 'mymymy' and event_ts = '2022-06-20 11:11:11' and event_id = 'event_id_1'
       ... IF update_ts < totimestamp('2022-06-21 12:12:12');
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid Arguments. Invalid date format
UPDATE test.mytable set payload = 'payload_updated'
WHERE h1 = '1' and h2 = 'return' and name = 'mymymy' and event_ts = '2022-06-20 11:11:11' and event_id = 'event_id_1'
IF update_ts < totimestamp('2022-06-21 12:12:12');
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 (ql error -304)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without the `totimestamp()` function call like this:

```
UPDATE test.mytable set payload = 'payload_updated'
WHERE h1 = '1' and h2 = 'return' and name = 'mymymy' and event_ts = '2022-06-20 11:11:11' and event_id = 'event_id_1'
IF update_ts < '2022-06-21 12:12:12';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yugabyte does upsert in a similar way to Postgres with ON CONFLICT

This example from their documentation on INSERT, if record already exists then prepend new dept name, it's a bit wordy for many fields but works.  All the conflict data is accessible via 'excluded'

INSERT INTO employees (employee_no, name, department)
VALUES (1, 'John Smith', 'Sales')
ON CONFLICT (name)
DO
UPDATE SET department = EXCLUDED.department || ';' || employees.department;

Comment: Note that the question was about YCQL (Cassandra like API) while your answer is for YSQL (PostgreSQL API).